# How to evaluate inference accuracy for seq2seq video captionnig model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

I've built a **video captionnig model**.
It consists of a Seq2seq model, taking video as input and outputting natural language

I obtain **really good test results** but horrible inference results:

```py
Epoch 1 ; Batch loss: 5.181570 ; Batch accuracy: 60.28% ; Test accuracy: 00.89%
...
Epoch 128 ; Batch loss: 0.628466 ; Batch accuracy: 96.31% ; Test accuracy: 00.81%
```

### Explanation

This accuracy is low because of my **accuracy function**: it compares **word by word** the given result with the caption.

This computation is adapted for training, because of teacher's forcing mechanism, but **not adapted for inference**.

#### Example

> [image: video1734]

**True descriptions:**

- `a football match is going on <end>`
- `the football player are made a goal <end>`
- `the crowd cheers as soccer players work hard to gain control of the ball <end>`

**Generated descrition:**

`a group of young men play a game of soccer <end>`

My model correctly understands what's happening, but it doesn't express it exaclty (word by word) like the awaited description...
For this specific example, accuracy value will be only 1/31.

#### How can I wisely compute inference accuracy ?

I thought about extracting the keywords of the sentences. Then trying to see if all keywords contained in the predicted sentence can be found somehere in the captions.
But I also have to check if the sentence is a correct english sentence...

Maybe you think about an easier way to compute accuracy. Tell me !

Answer (score 1):

User `Bleu Score` aka Bilingual Evaluation Understudy Score to compare hypotheses and references.

```py
def bleu_score(hypotheses, references):
    return nltk.translate.bleu_score.corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses)
```

Example:

```py
# two references for one document
from nltk.translate.bleu_score import corpus_bleu
references = [[['this', 'is', 'a', 'test'], ['this', 'is' 'test']]]
hypotheses = [['this', 'is', 'a', 'test']]
score = corpus_bleu(references, hypotheses)
print(score)
```

Output:

```py
1.0
```

Other methods are:

1. METEOR
2. ROUGE_L
3. CIDEr

Follow: https://github.com/arjun-kava/Video2Description/blob/VideoCaption/cocoeval.py

Comment: Humm, using BLEU score, I obtain a score of 1.6034157163765524e-231 for the same example. I think that BLEU is used for sentences that has the same meaning, but written in other way. Here, some captions describes different details in videos.

Comment: You can use other methods as updated in answer. Generally, versions of BLEU is standard for validating such kind of problems.